# Why a white screen is displayed after clicking on push notification in Android?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am sending a push via firebase, which on click goes to activity A where it checks a few conditions and if true goes to activity B where a fragment is opened.
Whenever the push is clicked it opens a white screen first, before starting activity A. 
This is especially bad when the app is running, even worse if the user is already in the fragment that is being  updated. The screen is all white, no toolbar even, it does not seem like it is the activity's xml either.

I tried

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

tried with `TaskStackBuilder` and without.

Method in Firebase message class:

```
private fun handleNotification(extras: Bundle, channelId: String, action: String) {
    val viewIntent = Intent(this, ActivityA::class.java)
    var stackBuilder: TaskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ActivityA::class.java)
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(viewIntent)
    viewIntent.putExtras(extras)
    viewIntent.action = action
    val piViewBill: PendingIntent? stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationId, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val normalView = RemoteViews(myapp.instance.packageName, R.layout.notification_layout)

    normalView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, messageBody)
    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(WalletDocApp.instance, channelId)     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification) 
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setCustomContentView(normalView)
            .setContentIntent(piViewBill) 
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
    val notification: Notification = notificationBuilder.build()
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
}
```

Code from Activity A (in a case where user is logged in):

```
 val i = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
 i.action = intent?.action
 intent?.extras.let {   i.putExtras(it) }
 i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
 finish()
 startActivity(i)
```

both activities are set to SingleTop in the manifest, I also tried SingleTask.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your activity theme so it has background that would match your application. That will make that white screen to display content of your own, but it's limited to images, sadly. I don't know if that solves your problem.
In your activity's theme style declaration add such `<item>`:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
```

Comment: An image won't do the job. Is this a known issue?